# not accessing the values of spinner | android

Tags: android, spinner

```
Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById(id);
String grades = spin.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

I have two activities, in both there are two spinners to which i am assigning entries and Id's programmatically. But later while getting the selected value in **ONE** activity my app crash. in other activity the code is running fine.

here is the code.

```
List<Integer> creditSpinnerArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
    creditSpinnerArray.add(i);

Spinner creditSpinner = new Spinner(this);

ArrayAdapter<Integer> creditAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, creditSpinnerArray);
creditAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

creditSpinner.setAdapter(creditAdapter);
creditSpinner.setId(Id][0]);
```

Comment: what is the type of array adapter you have assigned to the Spinner?

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: is your spinner attached to the activity? the layout in which your spinner is present should be loaded in each activity separately otherwise you Spinner "spin" will be null

Comment: @AndroidHacker , question is updated. look at the code

Comment: @bhargav , app is crashing so im not getting any log

Answer (score 0):

you question is not quite clear but as you are stating same code is working in another activity but not here than may be you are running in to issue with the type.

try this code to get the String like this

```
((Integer)spinner.getSelectedItem()).toString();
```

this is casting your selected item as the the type of the Object you have assigned to `ArrayAdapter<Integer>`

So in another words you should cast your spinner object depending on the Type of `Object` you have provided to the `ArrayAdapter<T>`

for Example

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    ((String)spinner.getSelectedItem()).toString();
```

or

```
ArrayAdapter<Object> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Object>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    ((Object)spinner.getSelectedItem()).toString();
```

the `toString()` just called to let you know what you can do with respective Object which you will get by no means I wrote a standard code

> Update

I can't see if you are adding your Spinner Object to the Activity UI, what am I missing here